# Convert an MFC CString to an unsigned integer

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++, mfc, type-conversion

I am trying to convert a CString to an unsigned int. I have looked up and got results for conversion to unsigned long but couldn't find anything for int as such. I know this is simple, but its kind of confusing me a bit.

Any suggestions?

Need something like this:

```
CString abc;
unsigned int xyz;

xyz = (unsigned int)abc;
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `_tcstoul` to get unsigned long value from string and then cast the value to unsigned int.